# How exactly enable 64 bit indexing in Octave on Windows 7(64 bit)

Tags: octave

I know this is an old topic. But still after exhausting search on Google I have no clue. I was fallowing along with Deep Learning tutorial on http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/tutorial/. On that tutorial in the SoftMax regression section I need to read 4704000 bytes( i.e images = fread(fp, 28*28*30000, 'uchar'). The script is working but too slow. Octave Using at most 500mb. I found that we should allow 64 bit indexing(https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Compiling-Octave-with-64_002dbit-Indexing.html). 
I am not sure how exactly I can enable 64 indexing in Windows Octave version 3.8.2.
Any suggestion or answers are welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

64 bit indexing is not something you enable. You must build Octave from source like that. That is not trivial in windows. The word configure in "Octave has to be configured with the option `--enable-64`", refers to the configure script that you run before actually building Octave, not to some configuration file or option you can run from Octave.

In addition, Octave dependencies such as BLAS and LAPACK will also need to be rebuilt from source with 64 bit which I am told is even less trivial. Even in Linux, most distributions will provide 32 bit builds only. See a [recent discussion on the mailing list](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Is-enable-64-still-experimental-td4669274.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is an experimental version for windows in
http://www.tatsuromatsuoka.com/octave/Eng/Win/
look for the `*-LA*` versions