# Octave Error: SparseMatrix::solve numeric factorization failed

Tags: octave

I have a large equation system to solve. The coefficients are stored in a sparse matrix CM of the dimension 320001 x 320001 elements, of which 18536032 are non-zero. The result vector B is 320001 elements long.

When executing

`I=CM\B`

> Octave Error: SparseMatrix::solve numeric factorization failed

I get the above error message. A brief look into the source code did not give me a clue.

Does anyone know what is causing that error?

BTW: when solving the same problem with a smaller matrix (e.g. 180001x180001) the program runs fine.

Johannes

Comment: Is there an easy way you can provide code that generates this sparse matrix or does it come from a complex/long code?

Comment: The matrix is created from 3 vectors using something like sparse(row, col, data). Each vector is 180001 elements long.

Comment: I tried to reduce the amount of memory needed, becuase I saw that the matrix consists of type double for all elements. My thought was that uning int32 for the indices and single for the data values should save memeory. However, Octave appears not to allow a mix of data types.

Comment: There is a reason for sparse matrices not accepting different data types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894231/matlab-uint8-sparse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octave uses [`UMFPACK`](https://github.com/PetterS/SuiteSparse/tree/master/UMFPACK) library to solve sparse linear systems. Inspecting the source shows that the error message is due to an error status with a negative value. List of error codes can be found in the [user's guide](https://github.com/PetterS/SuiteSparse/blob/master/UMFPACK/Doc/UserGuide.pdf). One of them is related to lack of enough memory:

> UMFPACK ERROR out of memory, (-1): Not enough memory. The ANSI C malloc or realloc routine failed.

Comment: I am running version 4.0.3, "x86_64-w64-mingw32".  Is that already 64bit data enabled or is there a 64bit version of Octave available?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29157629/how-exactly-enable-64-bit-indexing-in-octave-on-windows-764-bit) there are unofficial versions that have enabled 64bit indexing. You can download from [here](http://www.tatsuromatsuoka.com/octave/Eng/Win/).

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try

Comment: Update: with that 64bit array version I was able to solve an equation system with 2Mio variables. Thhe computation consumed 32GB memory (up to the last 300MB) and took 12 hours to run.

Comment: @corvairjo Good news!